# 'SFSafariViewController' is only available on iOS 9.0 or newer (React Native Build)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am able to run my React Native application in the simulator via Expo, but as soon as I try to build it with Xcode, I receive this error:

> 'SFSafariViewController' is only available on iOS 9.0 or newer (React
>   Native Build)

These are the steps I took to build.

1. Run `npm run eject`
2. Eject with 'ExpoKit' option
3. `cd` into the ios directory
4. Run `pod install`
5. Open up the xcworkspace file in Xcode
6. In both the project and the target, I changed the Deployment Target value to 11.0
7. Run the build to a iOS version 11 simulator

The build then fails with 7 of the above errors. I am using Xcode version 9.0, Pods version 1.3.1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I had the same issue after ejecting to ExpoKit. The answer by Xavier below works properly. Even though the project itself says it's targeting the latest version of iOS, you need to change the AppAuth pod.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For me, the errors were coming from the "AppAuth" dependency.
I fixed this issue by setting the "iOS Deployment Target" of this package to iOS 9.0.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It was definitely related to my pod deployment targets. Once I fixed them all up, I was good to go. Cheers!